# nvmem device tree naming pattern

Tags: linux-kernel, device-tree

In the [nvmem.yml](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/nvmem/nvmem.yaml) there is

```yaml
properties:
  $nodename:
    pattern: "^(eeprom|efuse|nvram)(@.*|-[0-9a-f])*$"
```

I have a hard time finding the pattern in the source code itself.
Where can I find that the nvmem device tree nodename must be 'eeprom' or 'efuse' or 'nvram'.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern doesn't exist in the code. The schema (nvmem.yaml) can be used to validate device trees but the kernel code doesn't enforce the node name.